# What's the mode hook for dired's minibuffer?

Tags: dired, minibuffer

Starting dired with `M-x dired` and hitting `M-x dired-create-directory` I am now in a mini-buffer. Which mode-hook do I use to set a keybinding for the mini-buffer?

Comment: Here is a link to something Drew wrote on a related issue, perhaps it can help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19759446/2112489

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is "this buffer" in which you want to set a keybinding? Is it the minibuffer? The Dired buffer? Dired does not have a special minibuffer, and neither does `M-x`. For `M-x` just use `minibuffer-local-must-match-map`. And I know of no function `dired-make-directory`. The minibuffer hooks are `minibuffer-exit-hook`, `minibuffer-inactive-mode-hook`, and `minibuffer-setup-hook`. And yes, see the URL that @lawlist mentioned for more info about minibuffer maps. But first, *please clarify what you are asking* - it is not at all clear.